# Hook before deleting a file in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Few days ago, I was assigned to task in wordpress. This task is to limit media folder capacity for each user. For example, each user can upload only files only for 100MB.  I found a really nice post, which explained and used hooks named `wp_handle_upload_prefilter` and `wp_handle_upload` for retrieving the file size and storing them before upload.

Right now, I need to know, or hook some function when user presses "Delete permanently" in media folder, so that I can recalculate the capacity of media folder for specific user. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else needs to react to deleted media, this was my solution to get around the issue that there's no delete media action:

```
function get_media_item_args( $args ) {

    if ($args["delete"] && $_GET["action" == "delete-post"])
    {
        $current_post_id = !empty( $_GET['id'] ) ? (int) $_GET['id'] : 0;

        if ($current_post_id > 0)
        {
            //Do your thing here.
        }
    }

    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'get_media_item_args', 'get_media_item_args', 10, 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use [delete_attachment](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/delete_attachment) hook for that. However, this one only affect files that is already attached to post.